# C# convert date to unix timestamp

Tags: c#, date, unix-timestamp

I have this date format `16 nov 02:12` I want convert it in unix time stamp but thats look to complex to me. I hope there is simple way to do that?

Comment: You have two problems. The first is _"Convert this weird format to a DateTime"_, and then _"Convert a DateTime to a unix timestamp"_. The latter has already been answered, and if you need help with the former, read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
   public static double DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime dateTime)

    {
       return (TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert the date to UTC?  The 1/1/1970 should be converted to UTC, not the dateTime.  You will still get same results, but it is more correct to convert  my way.

Comment: @jdweng could you please explain why your way is more correct?

Comment: The unix time 1,1,1970 is a UTC time.  In the code posted 1,1,1970 is local time which will vary depending on the timezone.